# How do i get the value of a remote event that is fired to the server?

Tags: luau

I am experiencing problems figuring out how to find/print the value(for now, later i am going to automate it).

`game.ReplicatedStorage.Events.GenerateNumber:FireServer() print(game.ReplicatedStorage.Events.GenerateNumber)`

i am trying to get the value of of the number generated by the remote event "GenerateNumber".

Answer (score 0):

To fire or transfer data through `RemoteEvents`, you have to specify them in the arguments of `:FireServer()`. But in this case you want to retrieve data as if it is a function, so you have to use a `RemoteFunction`.

A `RemoteFunction` is used as a normal function, but between the server and clients. The following code demonstrates what you want to do.

```lua
-- Client

local number = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction:InvokeServer()
print(number)

-- Server

function GenerateNumber()
    -- generate ur number, in this case the variable "number" is ur number
    local number = 5
    return number
end

game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction.OnServerInvoke = GenerateNumber
```

In the code, the client invokes the function by calling `:InvokeServer()`. The server detects the function being invoked and calls the function `GenerateNumber()`. The function returns a number, which is sent back to the client code that invoked the function.

> Note that you are not recommended to use `RemoteFunctions` if you don't have a good understanding of it because it can yield your script indefinitely if you do not return a value.

That's all, happy coding!